# Strange Issue with save_and_open_page

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I recently read an article about how you can use capybara's `save_and_open_page` method to make debugging tests in cucumber much easier. So I installed the `launchy` gem, wrote a "Show me the page" step in my step definitions file, and then tried to use that step in one of my feature files as a test. Here's what I got when I ran that feature file with cucumber:

```
  Scenario:                                                                                # features\training_records\view_training_records.feature:22
    Given I am signed in as "Ajedi32"                                                      # features/step_definitions/login_system_steps.rb:5
    And I am on the training class page for "Class 1"                                      # features/step_definitions/training_class_steps.rb:13
    And show me the page                                                                   # features/step_definitions/debug_steps.rb:7
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\ajedi32\My Documents\Workspace\rails_app>    And I click "View Training Records"
        # features/step_definitions/navigation_steps.rb:12
    Then show me the page                                                                  # features/step_definitions/debug_steps.rb:7

1 scenario (1 passed)
9 steps (9 passed)
0m7.533s
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\ajedi32\My Documents\Workspace\rails_app>
```

What??? I don't even...

It looks like `save_and_open_page` is printing the output of a blank command prompt to my console (yes, I am running Windows XP). It also does not save and open the page like it's supposed to. Do any of you have any clue what's happening here? I certainly don't...